# Is this an example of a ternary condition or is it something unrelated / different, i = j = 0?

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

I recently learned about ternary condition (specifically using : and ?, colons and questions marks, to create a condition that uses the question mark as an if statement, and the semicolon as a else statement. I recently came across the statement, `i = j = 0`. Is this the same type of condition? Is the statement saying:

```
if j = 0
{
    i == j
}
else
{
    i != j
}
```

Or is it referring to something different that I haven't learned yet, if so, please state what the statements purpose is, and how it works. Additionally, I couldn't find this exact question on the site, but if this is a duplicate, or if there is another website that you could refer we to that answers the question, I would be happy to delete to question, and then I would go and see what that website's information is. I would appreciate your input though, as I believe that this site does the best of any other site as for as explanations. Thank you all for your help! If you have any questions fell free to ask in the comments!

Comment: You say a ternary `specifically using : and ?` There is no `?`or `:` here, so how can it possibly be the same thing?

Comment: It's just an assignment to 2 independent variables, `i` & `j`

Comment: @Amit Thank you! I didn't know that there was such thing as a two part assignment statement.

Comment: @John3136 I thought that maybe there were different ways of creating a ternary statement. I didn't think that : and ? had to be specifically used to create one. Now, I know.

Comment: @John3136: The word “ternary” means composed of three items, not composed of colon and question mark. It is perfectly reasonable for a person who has learned that C has one ternary operation to think it might have others.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thank you, just because ternary means that a statement has to be composed of three items, doesn't mean it has to be : and ?, or at least that is what I originally thoughout.

Comment: @user7282043: This is not actually a two-part assignment statement. It is two assignment expressions. The first is `j = 0`. That sets `j` to 0, but is also has a value, the way `3 * 4` has the value 12. The value of an assignment expression is the value that was stored, so 0 in this case. This value is then used in the second (chronologically) expression, so it is in effect `i = 0`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil But, the values of j and i would be changed to zero from the statement correct?

Comment: @user7282043: Yes. But consider `x = y = 257` where `x` is an `int` and `y` is an (eight-bit) `unsigned char`. Because `y` is an `unsigned char`, 257 is converted to `unsigned char`, which wraps, producing 1. Then 1 is stored in `y`. That value is also stored in `x`. Even though `x` could hold 257, it receives the 1 that was stored in `y`, not the original 257.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Okay, I think I understand the topic of the two assignment expressions now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
i=j=0
```

This is just an assignment statement. After this line is executed, both variables will have a value of 0.

Comment: Specifically, `0` is assigned to `j`, and then the value of `j` is assigned to `i`. It is the same as `i = (j = 0)`, or `j = 0; i = j;`.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thank you, that is the what I was looking for in a comment that I posted above to Eric Postpischil, so it will still set j to 0, but then after that the second assigment will set i to j (or (you can think about it like) because of the transitive property i to 0).